# Tengo inconvenientes en copiar estilos de CSS

Tags: html5, css3, web

hice un index con su respectivo CSS, el index lo copio para lo que serian los enlaces, pero estos no copian del todo el estilo del CSS, me queda mal y no se cual es el problema.
Pegare el Index.html, el servicios.html y el estilos.css
gracias :D

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mi sitio Web</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/612199579a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">


</head>
```

SERVICIOS.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mi sitio Web</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/612199579a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
```

Comment: la línea de `estilos.css` en `servicio.html` ponelo abajo de los otros estilos, siempre te tiene que quedar abajo de todo las modificaciones que haces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

como se ve en la imagen, cuando ambos son exactamente los mismos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

EL CODIGO CSS seria este

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Otomanopee+One&display=swap');

body{
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Otomanopee One', sans-serif;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: dodgerblue;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: darkblue;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar{
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.lista-sm{
    display: block;
}
#navbar li{
    float: left;
}

#navbar  li a{
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
}

#navbar li.active a{
    color: red;
}

#navbar li a:hover{
    background-color: coral;
    color: black;
}

.myicono{
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}

#content{
    max-width: 1180px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2%;
}

#content header{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

#principal{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
#secundario{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

#content aside{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

#content footer{
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 25px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px){
    #content{
        padding: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    #content header{
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    #principal{
        padding: 3%;
        width: 45%;
    }

    #secundario{
        float: right;
        padding: 3%;
        width: 45%;
    }
    #content aside{
        clear: both;
        padding: 5%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content footer{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    #content{
        width: auto;
    }

    #principal{
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #secundario{
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #content aside{
        padding: 0;
        width: auto;
    }
    #content footer{
        width: auto;
    }

    .lista-sm{
        display: none;
    }
    #navbar li{
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
    #navbar li a{
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .myicono{
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto, va en la pregunta.. todas las publicaciones tienen un enlace editar debajo.. usalo, borra estas dos respuestas que no son respuestas, y agrega todo en la pregunta....